# Faster alternatives to Stanford CoreNLP for obtaining parse trees?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I love [Stanford CoreNLP](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), by now it is pretty accurate for my NLP needs. The problem is that analyzing massive amounts of text (let's say *millions* of sentences) takes *days*.

Are there alternative Java implementations that sacrifice some accuracy for efficiency while (ideally) providing the same API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the PCFG or factored models, you might consider switching to the new [RNN models](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/SocherBauerManningNg_ACL2013.pdf) that are available since version 3.2 - they are much faster.

Alternatively, if you only require dependencies, there are other parsers you could try (e.g. [mate-tools parser](https://code.google.com/p/mate-tools/) or the [ClearNLP dependency parser](http://clearnlp.wikispaces.com)). If you need constituents, you could try the [Berkeley parser](https://code.google.com/p/berkeleyparser/).

Afaik, there are no other parser implementations that have the same API as the Stanford Parser. However, there are collections that offer a rather uniform API to different parsers, e.g. [DKPro Core](https://code.google.com/p/dkpro-core-asl/) or [ClearTK](http://cleartk.github.io/cleartk/).

*Disclosure: I am a developer on the DKPro Core project.*

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the RNN models and report back here on accuracy and time.

Comment: Great! By upgrading from version 1.1.3 to 3.3.1 I got a 1.5x-1.8x speedup on my application, and very slight improvement on accuracy ( <1% ).